# How to print star pattern in JavaScript in a very simple manner?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have tried the code below but it's output is not proper!

```js
for(i=5;i>=1;i--) {
    for(j=i;j>=1;j--){
        console.log(j);
    }
        console.log("\n");
}
```

Comment: could you write how the required output looks?

Comment: You might want to explain what is the "star pattern" you're expecting?

Comment: What type of star pattern ?

Comment: 5 4 3 2 1
  4 3 2 1
    3 2 1
      2 1
       1
Either the numbers or the stars(*) in this pattern!!!!Like tht of a pyramind..

Answer (score 23):

```js
  for(var i=1; i<=4; i++){
       console.log("* ".repeat(i));
    }
```

```
/*
Output is: 
"*"
"* *"
"* * *"
"* * * *"
*/
```

Answer (score 13):

```html
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var i,j;
 for(i=1; i <= 5; i++)
 {
  for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
 {
   
   document.write('*');
  }
   document.write('<br />');
  }
    
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 12):

```
for (var line = "#"; line.length < 8; line += "#")
console.log(line);
```

Answer (score 6):

```js
            /** --------------

                    *
                   **
                  ***
                 ****
                *****
               ******
              *******
             ********
            *********


            ----------------*/

            let y = 10;
            let x = 10;

            let str = "";

            for(let i = 1; i < y; i++ ){
                for(let j = 1; j < x; j++){
                    if(i + j >= y){
                        str = str.concat("*");
                    }else{
                        str = str.concat(" ")
                    }
                }
                str = str.concat("\n")
            }

            console.log(str)


            /**_______________________



            *********
             ********
              *******
               ******
                *****
                 ****
                  ***
                   **
                    *


             _______________________*/

            let str2 = "";

            for(let i = 1; i < y; i++ ){
                for(let j = 1; j < x; j++){
                    if(i <= j ){
                        str2 = str2.concat("*");
                    }else{
                        str2 = str2.concat(" ")
                    }
                }
                str2 = str2.concat("\n")
            }

            console.log(str2)


            /**----------------------


            *
            **
            ***
            ****
            *****
            ******
            *******
            ********


             -------------------------*/


            let str3 = "";

            for(let i = 1; i < y; i++ ){
                for(let j = 1; j < x; j++){
                    if(i >= j ){
                        str3 = str3.concat("*");
                    }
                }
                str3 = str3.concat("\n")
            }

            console.log(str3)

            /**-------------------------


             *********
             ********
             *******
             ******
             *****
             ****
             ***
             **
             *

             ---------------------------*/
            let str4 = "";

            for(let i = 1; i < y; i++ ){
                for(let j = 1; j < x; j++){
                    if( j >= i ){
                        str4 = str4.concat("*");
                    }
                }
                str4 = str4.concat("\n")
            }

            console.log(str4)

            /**--------------------
             Diamond of Asterisks

                 *
                ***
               *****
              *******
             *********
              *******
               *****
                ***
                 *


             ---------------------*/

            let str5 = "";

            for(let i = 1; i < y; i++ ){
                for(let j = 1; j < x; j++){
                    if(i <= y / 2 && j >= (y / 2) - (i - 1) && j <= (y / 2) + (i - 1) ){
                        str5 = str5.concat("*");
                    }else if(i >= y / 2
                      && j > ((y / 2) -  i) * (-1)
                      && j < (y - ((y / 2) -  i) * (-1))){
                        str5 = str5.concat("*");
                    }
                    else {
                        str5 = str5.concat(" ");
                    }
                }
                str5 = str5.concat("\n");
            }

            console.log(str5)
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the simplest solution which I came across using only one for loop.

```
var a = '';
var n = 5;
var m = (n-1); 
for(i=1; i <= n; i++)
{
    a = a.trim();
    a = ' '.repeat(m) + a + (i > 1 ? ' ' : '') + '*';
    console.log(a);
    m--;
}
```

Output:

```
/**------------------------


    *
   * *
  * * *
 * * * *
* * * * *

---------------------------*/
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
for (var i = 7; i >= 1; i--) {
  var str = "";
  for (var j = i; j <= 7; j++) {
  str += "*";
     }
 console.log(str);
}
// This is example

// You can do this with any string and without using the function.
```

Answer (score 3):

**It's very simple, Try this code as below:**

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

      for(var j = 1; j<= i; j++) {

        document.write("*");  

      }

      document.write("<br/>");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        document.write('*');
    }
    document.write('<br />');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from your code, you are actually trying to print **stair** pattern rather than **star**.

Your main error consists in that `console.log` function prints every time on the next line.

```
for (var i = 5; i >= 1; i--) {
    var str = "";
    for (var j = i; j >= 1; j--) str += j;
    console.log(str);
}
```

JSFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/99wL8cbt/2/

Answer (score 1):

Just try it out

**Your Pyramid will be downwards like: **

```
4 3 2 1
 3 2 1
  2 1
   1

function stars(n){
    var str = '';
    for(var i=n; i>=1; i--){
        for(var k=n; k>=i; k--){
            str += "\t";
        }
        for(var j=i; j>=1; j--){
            str += j+"\t\t";
        }
        console.log(str);
        str = "";
    }
}
stars(3);
```

**Your Pyramid will be upwards like :**

```
  *
 * *
* * *

function stars(n){
    var str = '';
    for(var i=1; i<=n; i++){
        for(var k=1; k<=n-i; k++){
            str += "\t";
        }
        for(var j=1; j<=i; j++){
            str += "*\t\t";
        }
        console.log(str);
        str = "";
    }
}
stars(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function pyramid(n) {

    for(i=1 ;i<=n;i++) {

        let str = ' '.repeat(n-i);
        let str2 = '*'.repeat(i*2-1);
    console.log(str + str2 + str);
    }
}

pyramid(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

the log will output to a new line every time it is called, in chrome if it's the same it will just keep a count (not sure about other browsers). You want to collect the number of stars per line then output that after the inner loop has run

```js
for (var i = 5; i >= 1; i--) {
     var ouput = "";
     for (var j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
         ouput += "*"
     }
     console.log(ouput);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Maybe it will work for you:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i, j;
    //outer loop
    for(i = 0;i < 5; i++){
      //inner loop
      for(j = 0;j <= i; j++){
        document.write('*');
      }
      document.write('<br/>');
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
for(i=0;i<=5;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
    {
        document.write('*');
    }
    document.write('<br>')
}
```

Comment: This is more or less just a repeat of the existing answers.

Comment: You forgot to declare variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="test"></p>
    </body>
    <script>
        //Declare Variable
        var i;
        for(i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
            document.write('*'.repeat(i).concat("<br>"))
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
        //Declare Variable
        var i,j;

        //First Way
        for(i = 5; i >= 0; i--){
            for(j = 0; j <= i; j++){
                document.write('*');
            }
            document.write('<br>');
        }
        //Second Way
        for(i = 5; i >= 0; i--){
            document.write('*'.repeat(i).concat('<br>'))
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for(var a=1;a<8;a++){   
    var o="";  
    for(var b=1;b<=a;b++){  
        o +="#";    
    }   
    debug(o);   
}
```

Try above code.

Output:

```
--> #
--> ##
--> ###
--> ####
--> #####
--> ######
```

Answer (score -1):

This below code worked for me

```
for(i= 0; i< n; i++){

   col = i;
   for(j = 0; j< n- col;j++){
       process.stdout.write('');
   }
   for (j = 1;j< col+2;j ++){
       process.stdout.write('#');
   }
   process.stdout.write('\n');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    //Declare Variable
    var i, j;
    //outer loop
    for(i = 0; i <= 25; i++){
    //inner loop
    for(j = 0; j <= i; j++){
    document.write("*");
    }
    document.write('<br>');
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score -1):

**Here is the solution in javascript while loop:**

```
> var i = 0, out = '';
>  while( i <= 4)
>     {
>       out = out + '* ';
>       document.write('<br> '+ out);
>       i++;
>     } 
>  
> document.write('<br>');
```

Answer (score -2):

### Try this one for diamond pattern in javascript

```
<head>
 <style>
    p{text-align:center;margin-left:20px;}
 </style>
</head>

<body>
   <h1>JavaScript patterns</h1>
   <p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  var x=function(n){
    document.write("<center>");

  var c="";
    for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
      c=c+"#";
      document.write(c);
      document.write("<br>");  
   }

    for(var k=n;k>0;k--){
      for(var j=0; j<(k-1); j++){
       document.write("#");
      } 
    document.write("<br>");
   }   
  }
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x(10);

</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

**You can try this**

```
 var x, y, space = "",
    star = "",
    n = 4,
    m = n - 1;
for (x = 1; x <= n; x++) {
    for (y = m; y >= 1; y--) {
        space = space + (" ");
    }
    m--;
    for (let k = 1; k <= x * 2 - 1; k++) {
        star = star + "*"
    }
    console.log(space + star)
    space = '';
    star = "";
}
```