# Node.js Pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

```
var readline=require("readline-sync");
var n=parseInt(readline.question());

for (var i=1;i<=n;i++){
  var str="";
for (var j=1;j<=i;j++){
str+="*";
  console.log(str);

}console.log();

}
```

> Plesse tell me where I am doing wrong .
> I want to print a pattern for

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Also please tell me where I can do improvements. Thanks !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print star pattern in JavaScript in a very simple manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365737/how-to-print-star-pattern-in-javascript-in-a-very-simple-manner)

Answer (score 0):

You need to know better about variable scopes. `var` is hoisted to the module level that why `str` is not defined on each iteration of your outer `for` loop.
See [Closure](https://javascript.info/closure)

Just use `let` instead of `var` to define `str` in a `for` block scope.

```
for (var i=1;i<=n;i++){
  let str="";
  for (var j=1;j<=i;j++){
    str+="*";
    console.log(str);
  }
  console.log();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing that string every time you append a * to string. and you can fix it using following

```js
n=5
for (var i=0;i<n;i++){
  var str="";
  for (var j=0;j<=i;j++){
    str+="*";
   
  }
   console.log(str);
 

}
```

Comment: Sir I need to print the pattern. Please dry run your own code and then say whether this is correct or not.

Comment: There is run snippet button just click on it you'll get console output !!